# Making a JS function return available to other functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, return

I have a function:

```
removePastUsersFromArray().then(function(promises){
      var arrayOfPastUsers = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < promises.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < promises[i].length; j++){
            arrayOfPastUsers.push(promises[i][j]);
        }
     }
})
```

How can I make `arrayOfPastUsers` available to other functions? So far if I call this function and then log `arrayOfPastUsers` it says it is undefined. I would like to be able to access the array or pull it into another function so I can evaluate it against another.

I tried adding in `return arrayOfPastUsers` which didn't help. and I also tried adding in the line:

`return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){   resolve(arrayOfPastUsers);)}` which also did not solve it

Comment: Why would you compare an array of `Promise` objects to other objects? To answer your question, just declare the `arrayOfPastUsers` in the scope you want to access it.

Comment: You're going to run into the problems involved with asynchronous code. Even if you arrange for other code to have access to that array, how can you be sure that the `.then()` callback has been called before the other code access it?

Comment: @DanielB that's what im saying though. I have a promise.all that gives me 2 arrays. I have combined them into 1 array (arrayOfPastUsers) and then I want that array to be made available in another function and not sure how to do that

Comment: @Pointy there must be a way to do this though surely? surely arrays can be made available to other functions?

Comment: @JaromandaX what i mean is. what ever objects are in that array can be used by another function.

Comment: @JaromandaX it isn't vague. it's obvious what im trying to do, but i just dont know how to implement it. i could go globals but globals are bad practice right. can you not give me a suggestion of what is a good idea and i can try and work with that

Comment: @JaromandaX alright thanks. no need to be patronising though.

Answer (score 1):

Easy approach would be declaring 'arrayOfPastUsers' outside of the success callback for your promise and just assigning it inside it. This would make you to use the variable anywhere with in the scope of the outer function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function container(removePastUsersFromArray){
  var arrayOfPastUsers = [];
  removePastUsersFromArray().then(function(promises){

      for(var i = 0; i < promises.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < promises[i].length; j++){
            arrayOfPastUsers.push(promises[i][j]);
        }
     }
  })
  return arrayOfPastUsers ;
}

var myArr= new container(removePastUsersFromArray);

//myArr will be full **after** promise fulfill
```

This will create a closure.

Answer (score 0):

U can always make it a global array.